# How to add a shortcut do file on normal project Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, shortcut

how do I add in a Visual Studio 2008 a shortcut to a file. CS from another project?

Answer (score 6):

In the [Add Existing Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92.aspx) dialog (<kbd>Shift+Alt+A</kbd>), use Add as Link after selecting the path to the existing file:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Darin Dimitrov.
It was exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @user1245087, if this post was helpful you may consider [marking it as answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the tick next to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can select to add a file to a folder in your project and browse to the file in the other project.

However, it is advised to put such 'common/generic' files in a separate project and include that generic project in both solutions.

Comment: The Darin Dimitrov said exactly what I wanted.

Comment: yes you are right ... maybe you can take my remark into account (if it is worth the extra time).