# How to make VS NOT copy my C# File

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have a solution and a few projects in it. Then there's a Utils file I just Made and added to the solution. But when I want to use this file from any of the projects in the solution, it gets copied in the project's folder.

So If I use it in 10 projects, it gets copied 10 times. How can I avoid this and make the projects search for that file in the their solution's folder?

Comment: You can add the file to your solution as a link. You can find a [pictorial here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9533599/661933)

Comment: Wouldn't the corect way be to build that c# code into an assembly, and to reference that assmbly from the other assemblies that use this code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the *Add Existing Item* dialog box, select the *Add As Link* operation instead of *Add*. You find it in the dropdown-esque menu inside the *Add* button.

You could also put the shared code into a separate assembly. In my opinion, solutions with lots of linked files are more confusing, while separate projects can show the structure the developer had in mind when developing.

Answer (score 1):

When adding the file, select it
, click on the arrow on the Open/Add button and then choose open as link.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need a bit more clarification. Is this Utils file a source file or a binary reference? If it is a source file, why not just add it to one common project and reference that project from all your others? If it is a binary reference that you don't want to copy, set the reference's **Copy Local** property to "false" in the Property Grid, which leaves the binary reference in place.